# Returning term position in a document with scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I know scikit-learn follows the bag-of-words assumption/model according to the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_extraction.html). However, is there a way to extract the term position while tf-idf is being calculated?

For example, if I have these documents

```
document1 = "foo bar baz"
document2 = "bar bar baz"
```

Can I somehow get this (a tuple/list of term_id)

```
document1_terms = (1, 2, 3)
document2_terms = (2, 2, 3)
```

or (a dictionary of term, with a tuples of position as value)

```
document1_terms = {1: (1, ), 2: (2, ), 3: (3, )}
document2_terms = {2: (1, 2), 3: (3, )}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some trial and error, I found the solution to this problem. First create the posting

```
vectorizer = CountVectorizer()

term_doc_freq = vectorizer.fit_transform(collection['document'])
```

then represent each document with a tuple of term-ids with this

```
from functools import partial
def document_get_position(row, vectorizer):
    result = tuple()

    for token in vectorizer.build_tokenizer()(row['document']):
        result = result + (vectorizer.vocabulary_.get(token),)

    return result

positions = collection.apply(partial(document_get_position,
                                     vectorizer=vectorizer),
                             axis=1)
```

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean this?

```
In [13]: from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

In [14]: vectorize = CountVectorizer(min_df=1)

In [15]: document1 = "foo bar baz"
    ...: document2 = "bar bar baz dee"
    ...: 

In [16]: documents = [document1, document2]

In [17]: d = vectorize.fit_transform(documents)

In [18]: vectorize.vocabulary_
Out[18]: {u'bar': 0, u'baz': 1, u'dee': 2, u'foo': 3}

In [19]: d.todense()
Out[19]: 
matrix([[1, 1, 0, 1],
        [2, 1, 1, 0]], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: Actually, he's not looking for this. You're making a vocabulary for the entire document set. The OP is apparently looking for a dictionary at "document-level".

Comment: no, I am not looking to convert sparse matrix to dense matrix, and @Radu Gheorghiu, not really dict at document-level, but more like attempting to somehow represent each document with term-ids, and their respective position(s) in the document